# Console log statement not showing up at all in console with Chrome Extension API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am attempting to cycle through one of my bookmarks folders and log the title and url of the bookmarks from the array. Whenever I am trying to log the array for testing, an object doesn't appear at all, nothing is null or undefined. The first 2 logs show the arrays with their designated nodeTree location. What am I missing in the function to return the title and url of each bookmark to the console?

```
    chrome.bookmarks.getTree(function(bmTree){
        bmTree.forEach(function(node){
            console.log(node);
            // * Variables are hardcoded for development
            // * reaches Resources folder in Coding Folder
            // TODO: declare variable = to userInput from bookmark tree
            let list = node.children[0].children[2].children[1];
            console.log(list);
            // Retrieve bookmarks title and url
            for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
                const bkmk = [
                    list.children[i].title,
                    list.children[i].url
                ];
                console.log(bkmk);             
            };
        });
    })
};
```

[image]

Comment: so, what is the picture? `node.children[0].children[2].children[1];` is not likely going to be anything with a `.length` - what is it supposed to be?

Comment: @Bravo It is the previous log sorted to the content that should be displayed in the current log, to show where the ".title" and ".url" came from.

Comment: so is it one of `console.log(node);` or `console.log(list);`?

Comment: It is the very bottom "console.log(bkmk)" that is not functioning correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was a simple tweak, instead of using `list.length`, I needed to use `list.children.length`. Code samples below:

Original:

```
    chrome.bookmarks.getTree(function(bmTree){
    bmTree.forEach(function(node){
        console.log(node);
        // * Variables are hardcoded for development
        // * reaches Resources folder in Coding Folder
        // TODO: declare variable = to userInput from bookmark tree
        let list = node.children[0].children[2].children[1];
        console.log(list);
        // Retrieve bookmarks title and url
        for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
            const bkmk = [
                list.children[i].title,
                list.children[i].url
            ];
            console.log(bkmk);             
        };
    });
})
```

Fixed:

```
const getBookmarks = () =>{
chrome.bookmarks.getTree(function(bmTree){
    bmTree.forEach(function(node){
        console.log(node);
        // * Variables are hardcoded for development
        // * reaches Resources folder in Coding Folder
        // TODO: declare variable = to userInput from bookmark tree
        let list = node.children[0].children[2].children[1];
        console.log(list);
        // Retrieve bookmarks title and url
        for (let i = 0; i < list.children.length; i++){
            var bkmk = [list.children[i].title, list.children[i].url];

            console.log(bkmk);           
        }; 
    });
})
```